# Which of these "Email campaign status" combinations make the most sense? (color status labels)

Tags: color, labels, email, status

Me and the team are split on which combination of colors are best to indicate "Active", "Sending", and "Sent" for both one-time & automated/recurring email campaigns.

These would be used to indicate the status of each campaign in a list.

[image: 3 versions of the status indicators on an email campaign.]

Answer (score 0):

It's an email marketing tool right? If so I would choose B. Assuming there are 5 recipients in the list and I want to check the email status. Sending is a real short-time action and it will not appear at the same time with sending ,so i would consider sending=sent, unless it failed but it will turn to a different color, so it doesn't matter. In that way, you can differentiate sending/sent and active. (I suppose active would show near the sending/sent). So B is better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This is a status for the whole campaign, so not used to indicate each recipients status - not sure if that changes your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Having the possibility of unifying activities according to the type of action they execute, I would not hesitate to group items:

[image]

Following this, option C is the most accurate.

Comment: Agree with this and would be beneficial to keep some visual distinction between "Sending" and "Sent" because it could be easy to confuse them when glancing quickly. A clock icon on the "Sending" chip could add even more distinction, especially for people with colorblindness.